# Is there a way to add multiple choices dynamically to select2 dropdown?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

Is there a way to add multiple choices dynamically to select2 dropdown? I was able to add one choice using `createSearchChoice` tag of select2. I am using select2 3.5.2 and single-select select2 dropdown. I need multiple choices to be added on search. For example: If I search for 'eggs' in select2 input, the options in select2 dropdown should be something like 
`Class-A eggs`
`Class-B eggs`

Sample code for creating one choice on search:

```
$('#some-id').select2({
    createSearchChoice: function (term) {
        return { id: term, text: "Some text" + term};   
    },
    multiple: false, data: [{id: "foo", text:"foo"},{id:"bar", text:"bar"}]
});
```

Comment: can you show us your code and a basic jsfiddle

Comment: I added sample code. Please check.